# wx.Miniframe don't move on screen after updating wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm on Linux.
I have a piece of code that runs a miniframe.
Before updating the wxPython module, my code was working perfectly.
Now I have a problem.
The miniframe appears on the screen but can no longer be moved with the mouse.

Code snippet for testing:

```py
import wx

class MiniFrame(wx.MiniFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.MiniFrame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Mini Frame', 
                size=(300, 100))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, size=(300, 100))
        button = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Close Me", pos=(15, 15))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCloseMe, button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnCloseWindow)

    def OnCloseMe(self, event):
        self.Close(True)

    def OnCloseWindow(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    MiniFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

On the other hand I notice that by modifying the inheritance, ie by replacing wx.MiniFrame by wx.Frame it works.

The problem seems to come from the original wx.MiniFrame class.
Or am I thinking there is a property to change?

WxPython version (pip show wxpython on Ubuntu 22.04.1) :

*Name: wxPython*

*Version: 4.0.7*

*Summary: Cross platform GUI toolkit for Python, "Phoenix" version*

Comment: You can try to play around with the style flags on creation, "CAPTION | SYSTEM_MENU | RESIZE_BORDER" could be a first try.

Comment: You don't mention which version of wxpython or Linux. On Mint/Ubuntu 20 using wxpython '4.1.1 gtk3 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.5' your code works as expected i.e. it moves . p.s. use `app = wx.App()` rather than `app = wx.PySimpleApp()` which is deprecated.

Comment: Rold of Saxony, it does'nt change anything. It seems to be relative to some changes made to the wx.miniframe module

Comment: Try looking in here for the latest version of wxpython: https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-20.04/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem persists. I think best way is finally to send a message to wxpython developpers community because the problem seems to be relative to the module itself